# how to set php-rewrite on mamp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

I am using mamp on my mac for php devolpement.
For several days ,I want to set my php-rewrite on mamp;on my windows ,i have set php-rewrite successfully 2 months ago.

Now , the php-rewrite works ,I can visit my page without index.php in URL but, I can't visit .html files. When I try to visit `.html` files, the browser says:

> You don't have permission to access
>   /application/views/admin/login.html on this server.

My `.htaccess` is setting as below,my framework is codeigniter:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm wating for the anwser,thanks!

Comment: sounds like what it says, a permission error, add nested permissions to the working directory `/application/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the folder's permissions from SSH to make it readable to "world":

```
chmod -R 775 /application/views/admin/
```

Or just right-click the file from your IDE and change permissions manually

Comment: Then make sure the folder you're in has the same permissions (start by giving 'admin' readable by 'world' permissions, if it doesn't work, go for the 'views' folder and so on)

Comment: Thanks,and could you tell me how to set 'admin' folder readable by 'world' permissions?

Comment: The same way – right click on the 'admin' folder and check the 'read' box under 'world', if you are not doing it from ssh